# Compile V8 on linux platform failed

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

compile the latest v8 failed on linux platform.

linux, v8 using ninjia

ninja: Entering directory `out.gn/x64.release'
[14/571] LINK ./mksnapshot
 o/x/args.gn+                                                                                                        buffers
FAILED: mksnapshot
../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -pie -Wl,--fatal-warnings -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--as-needed -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--icf=all -Wl,--color-diagnostics -m64 -rdynamic -pie -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--gc-sections -o "./mksnapshot" -Wl,--start-group @"./mksnapshot.rsp"  -Wl,--end-group   -latomic -ldl -lpthread -lrt
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: void std::atomic_init(std::atomic*, bool)

> > > referenced by module-compiler.cc:260 (../../src/wasm/module-compiler.cc:260)
> > >                     obj/v8_base_without_compiler/module-compiler.o:(v8::internal::wasm::CompilationState::New(std::shared_ptr const&, std::shared_ptr))

link error

Comment: Which version of V8, and how did you get it? Which distro/version of Linux? Looks like some dependency is missing, related to `-latomic` / `std::atomic_init()`.

Comment: the lastest version of v8 -- 4bc72b88cf7f3e0d21c62272b41d19897925eab2. linux version is debian 8.

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 8.11

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved by replacing std::atomic_init with straight assignment.